# .htaccess Wildcard Passthrough Redirect

Tags: htaccess, web-hosting

I use a LiteSpeed web hosting server on `*.example.com` and I am currently using this code in my `.htaccess` file for it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1 [L,R=302]
```

This code makes `1.example.com` redirect to `example.com/1`, which is great. But there are a couple of things that need fine-tuning with this:

- `1.2.example.com` redirects to `example.com/1.2`, but I would rather `1.2.example.com` redirect to `example.com/2/1` if possible.
- Files are also inaccessible when this `.htaccess` code is present. I
  would like files to be accessible too.

(Yes, a multi-level wildcard is set up and working).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1 [L,R=302]
> ```

Currently, you are capturing the URL-path (ie. `^(.*)$`) but not making use of this, so any requests for files are redirected back to the "subdomain" subdirectory (which I assume is what you mean by being "inaccessible").

You are also missing the trailing slash on the target URL (ie. `https://example.com/%1`), so assuming this is a subdirectory then a second redirect will occur that auto-appends the trailing slash. (Appending the URL-path - see below - naturally resolves this issue.)

> `1.2.example.com` redirects to `example.com/1.2`, but I would rather `1.2.example.com` redirect to `example.com/2/1` if possible.

Assuming you only have subdomains and sub-subdomains then I would implement this as a separate rule.

> **UPDATE:** it somehow needs to first check to see if a file exists before performing the wildcard redirect.

Ah, OK, if you are intending to serve static files from the subdomain then you'll need to include a filesystem check to make sure the requested file does not already map to a file.

Try the following instead:

```
# Subdomain redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L]

# Sub-Subdomain redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%2/%1/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the URL-path captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Whereas `%1` (and `%2`) are backreferences to the preceding `RewriteCond` (the last matched *CondPattern*).

`(.*)` is the same as `^(.*)$` since regex is greedy by default.

Comment: That's working. Thanks. The trailing slash isn't needed though, so I modified it slightly.

Comment: @RyderCragie What do you mean by "Files are also inaccessible ... I would like files to be accessible too."? What should happen when you request something like `foo.example.com/image/file.jpg`? Do you still need to be able to access files on the subdomain (or sub-subdomain)?

Comment: Yes. So if I host a file from the wildcard and try to view it from 1.example.com/test.txt, it will send me to example.com/1. So it somehow needs to first check to see if a file exists before performing the wildcard redirect.

Comment: @RyderCragie I'm also assuming that the subdomain should redirect to a subdirectory off the main domain (not a file or anything). Is that the case?

Comment: ONLY IF a file doesn't exist on the wildcard hosting, yes.

Comment: Also, the code you provided is sending 1.2.example.com to example.com/1/2. I'd like 1.2.example.com to go to example.com/2/1 if possible please.

Comment: @RyderCragie Ah, OK - you'll need to add a filesystem check. Sorry, I got the sub-subdomains round the wrong way (I didn't just notice you wanted these reversed). I've updated my answer. However, when redirecting to the subdirectory (off the main domain) do you want to discard the URL-path? eg. `1.example.com/does-not-exist.txt` to `example.com/1/` (note the trailing slash)?

Comment: Once again I have removed the trailing slash from your code after trying it again, because it isn't needed. But it does work and it does things in the right order.

In terms of files being accessible, I just want any files I upload to the wilcard to be accessible publicly. So if I put a file in the root directory, it should be accessible from random-subdomain.example.com/test.txt. Currently it isn't. It just goes to example.com/random-subdomain.

Comment: @RyderCragie "Currently it isn't." - Have you added the filesystem _conditions_ in my updated answer? "I have removed the trailing slash" - So, you are not redirecting to a directory? Are you redirecting to a file? But without a file-extension this needs additional processing (is this related to your extensionless URLs from previous questsions)?

Comment: That is working now! Oh, before I forget, I should probably ask this too as an added extra (not needed but I'd like it to work): is 1.example.com/2 > example.com/1/2 possible IN ADDITION to all this? The reason I've left this till last is because I don't know if that's possible without breaking everything else we've added.

Comment: "So, you are not redirecting to a directory? Are you redirecting to a file? But without a file-extension this needs additional processing (is this related to your extensionless URLs from previous questions)?" - Yes. There is more to it but I won't make it any more confusing than it needs to be/already is.

Comment: Also, the, what I’ll call the “path-flipper” only works for 2 sub-subdomains. Is there any way to have that part work infinite without adding the code manually for each one?

Comment: Those are the last 2 questions I have. Sorry about the hassle and thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, maybe I have 3. www.test.example.com goes to example.com/test/www. I'd like the www's to be completely ignored and for it to just go to example.com/test.